# Как закрыть текущее активити и начать новое?

Tags: android, activity

Здравствуйте, у меня есть следующая цепочка активити:

```
MainActivity -> Activity1(если первый раз) -> Activity2 -> MainActivity
```

Первым делом `MainActivity` проверяет первый ли раз она запущена и ,если первый, запускает `Activity1`, но после запуска она должна закрыться и не выполнять код далее. Я использую метод `finish`, но он не помогает. Код:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
firstTime = false;

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = save_start_inf.edit();
editor.putBoolean("FirstTime", firstTime);
editor.commit();

Log.i(TAG, "First time");
startActivty(intent);
this.finish();

Log.i(TAG, "Check");
```

В логах:

```
First time
Check
...
```

Comment: Покажите код.

Comment: intent = new Intent(this,Activity1.class);\n
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();

всегда работало. Если не работает то покажите код все же

Comment: @falstaf @Nuclominus Я добавил код

Comment: По вашему коду видно, что вы только создаёте `Intent`, но не запускаете новую `Activity`.

Comment: @falstaf прошу прощения. Ошибка форматирования

Comment: Этот код содержится в `onCreate()`, верно я понимаю?

Comment: @falstaf Да, конечно

Comment: То, что выполнение кода доходит до     Log.i(TAG, "Check");

Comment: после this.finish(); напишите return;

Answer (score 1):

finish() добавляет задание в очередь на завершение потока activity, но завершение сработает только после завершения выполняемого метода. В вашем случае, если вы не хотите чтобы после finish() сразу завершилось текущее activity, добавьте в метод return.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте добавить/изменить следующий **код:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewClass.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score -1):

После вызова метода `this.finish();` используйте `return;`

```
Log.i(TAG, "First time");
startActivty(intent);
this.finish();
return;
```